# Python efficient sorting algorithm with three-way tiebreaker

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to implement a (three-way) tie-breaking procedure that you might see in (US) sports.  I want to first sort by wins and if tied use the head to head tiebreaker.

I need this to be the runtime to be as fast as possible, I don't really care about the memory requirements.  If there is a better way to represent my data such that it is easy that is also a useful answer.

The data I want to sort has at most 15 values, so the runtime isn't bad in that regard, I just want to do this 100k times.

Pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
Iterator = 0    
maxVal = max value of wins
maxes = teams with wins == maxVal
If len(maxes) == 1
    rank[values] = iterator
    iterator += 1
    sort(restOfData)
Else 
    # H2Hwins computes the amount of wins for teams currently tied incase of 2 or more teams tied  
    counts = sorted([(h2hwins(t, maxes), pointDifferential) for team in maxes])
    for c in counts
        rank[value] = iterator
        iterator += 1
    sort(restOfData)
return rank
```

So if I had the following inputs, these would be the outputs:

```
# Columns are Team, Wins, H2H Tiebreaks, Point Differential
# Lakers win tie based on H2H with Clippers
testData = [['Lakers', 48, ['Clippers'], 6], ['Clippers', 48, ['Warriors'], 8], ['Warriors', 47, ['Lakers'], 10]]
magicSort(testData)
>>> ['Lakers', 'Clippers', 'Warriors']

# Warriors have 2 H2H tiebreakers so they are 1st.  Lakers have 1 H2H tiebreaker so they are 2nd.
testData2 = [['Lakers', 48, ['Clippers'], 6], ['Clippers', 48, [''], 8], ['Warriors', 48, ['Lakers', 'Clippers'], 10]]
magicSort(testData2)
>>> ['Warriors', 'Lakers', 'Clippers']

# All 3 are tied so we default to point differential
testData3 = [['Lakers', 47, ['Clippers'], 6], ['Clippers', 47, ['Warriors'], 8], ['Warriors', 47, ['Lakers'], 10]]
magicSort(testData3)
>>> ['Warriors', 'Clippers', 'Lakers']
```

I can come up with more test cases if needed, but I believe this covers edge cases

Comment: By the way your input data format is seriously weird, it's a recursively-nested list, not a list-of-tuples. Why on earth are you using that format, it'll be a pain to process? Did it come from a scraper or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated answer: you want a **sort algorithm which breaks three-way ties in your defined order of fields: a) Wins b) Number of H2H Tiebreaks c) Point Differential**

I recommend using pandas anytime you want to do something complicated using data (such as a multi-key sort, like this).
First, we have to massage your strange data format (recursively nested list) into a useable form to build a dataframe:

- list of 4-tuples: `Team, Wins, H2H_Tiebreaks, Point_Differential`

  - note that `H2H_Tiebreaks` should be a tuple, even if it has length 1 or 0. Strictly we only care about its length (`Num_H2H_Ties`), not its contents
- then we do `df.sort_values(by=['Wins','Num_H2H_Ties', 'Point_Differential'], ascending=False)`. Code at bottom:

  - if you only want the winning team's row, do `.iloc[0]`
  - if you only want the winning team's name, do `.iloc[0, 0]`

Solution:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['Team', 'Wins', 'H2H_Tiebreaks', 'Point_Differential']

# 1) Lakers win tie based on H2H with Clippers
dat = [('Lakers', 48, ('Clippers',), 6), ('Clippers', 48, ('Warriors',), 8), ('Warriors', 47, ('Lakers',), 10)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dat, columns=cols)

# 2) Warriors have 2 H2H tiebreakers so they are 1st.  Lakers have 1 H2H tiebreaker so they are 2nd.
dat2 = [('Lakers', 48, ('Clippers',), 6), ('Clippers', 48, (), 8), ('Warriors', 48, ('Lakers', 'Clippers'), 10)]
df2  = pd.DataFrame(data=dat2, columns=cols)

# 3) All 3 are tied so we default to point-differential
dat3 = [('Lakers', 47, ('Clippers',), 6), ('Clippers', 47, ('Warriors',), 8), ('Warriors', 47, ('Lakers',), 10)]
df3  = pd.DataFrame(data=dat3, columns=cols)

############    
df1['Num_H2H_Ties'] = df1['H2H_Tiebreaks'].apply(len)
df1.sort_values(by=['Wins','Num_H2H_Ties', 'Point_Differential'], ascending=False)

# Result:
       Team  Wins H2H_Tiebreaks  Point_Differential  Num_H2H_Ties
1  Clippers    48   (Warriors,)                   8             1
0    Lakers    48   (Clippers,)                   6             1
2  Warriors    47     (Lakers,)                  10             1

############
df2['Num_H2H_Ties'] = df2['H2H_Tiebreaks'].apply(len)
df2.sort_values(by=['Wins','Num_H2H_Ties', 'Point_Differential'], ascending=False)

# Result:
   Team  Wins       H2H_Tiebreaks  Point_Differential  Num_H2H_Ties
2  Warriors    48  (Lakers, Clippers)                  10             2
0    Lakers    48         (Clippers,)                   6             1
1  Clippers    48                  ()                   8             0
############
df3['Num_H2H_Ties'] = df3['H2H_Tiebreaks'].apply(len)
df3.sort_values(by=['Wins','Num_H2H_Ties', 'Point_Differential'], ascending=False)

# Result:
       Team  Wins H2H_Tiebreaks  Point_Differential  Num_H2H_Ties
2  Warriors    47     (Lakers,)                  10             1
1  Clippers    47   (Warriors,)                   8             1
0    Lakers    47   (Clippers,)                   6             1
```

and here as a function:

```
def sort_nway_tiebreaker(df):

    # Filter only teams with max-Wins
    df = df[df['Wins'] == df['Wins'].max()]

    df['Num_H2H_Ties'] = df['H2H_Tiebreaks'].apply(len)

    df = df.sort_values(by=['Wins','Num_H2H_Ties', 'Point_Differential'], ascending=False)

    return df.iloc[0]
```

Comment: So the hacky way won't work if there's a 3 team tie.

Comment: @qwertylpc: didn't think of that, the OP only asked about a two-way tiebreaker; I didn't know American sports can generate three-way ties. Sure you could generalize the method, but yes it'd be clunky and inelegant, and since the OP didn't ask for it, I'm not going to code it. But it can be done.

Comment: I am op.  Maybe I was a bit unclear as that was part of the question.  The final example has them all tied in a 3 way tie

Comment: Apologies your question is much more complicated than seemed at first glance due to resolving n-way ties. I totally revised my answer. Now uses pandas `sort_values()` method not Python heaps.